# startActivity of ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE cause OpenGL render to go black, even after removal

Tags: android, android-intent, opengl-es, bluetooth

I am trying to add bluetooth support to my OpenGL based Android game.
However, when setting a new intent startActivity or startActivityForResult the OpenGL render in the background goes black.
I am starting the intent from within a pop up window so you can see the OpenGL render in the background up until the point the new intent kicks in.

The intent I am setting is BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION
When an alert show for confirmation only when I press it it turns black, not before.
The code I am using to create the new intent is:

```
    if (finalAdapter.getScanMode() !=
            BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
            discoverableIntent.putExtra("Theme", "Transparent");
            a.startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, 42);
    }
```

I have tried to set the style to make the intent transparent and show the OpenGL thinking maybe the intent's background is Opaque.
Even if I accept the intent being black opaque I can't even restore the OpenGL rendering after attempting to remove this intent with finishActivity

The code for removing the intent is

```
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            a1.finishActivity(42);
            self.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

The game logic still works and the render update function is still being called. It's just that the screen is black.
Maybe I need to reload the OpenGL resources? Which would seem odd?
Is the intent actually being removed? Why do I get a black screen?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Apparently when I call startActivity onPause and onResume are being called respectively for the main activity.
I handle OpenGL in case of onRestart and onStop but when only onPause and onResume are called I don't reload OpenGL properly.
That was the issue.